# Why isnt Send implemented for a struct containing Arc?

Tags: multithreading, rust, traits

I'm using [a crate](https://docs.rs/postgres/0.17.5/postgres/struct.Client.html) to interact with Postgres with simply writing sql queries by hands (Diesel seems for my simple case) and got stuck about the multithreaded access to the database client. Here is the code:

```
use postgres::Client;

pub struct Database{
    connection: Arc<Client>
}

impl Database {
    pub fn from_config(url: &str) -> Database {
        //...
    }
}

fn main() {
    let url: String = //...
    let db = db::Database::from_config(&url);
    let db_ref = Arc::new(db);
    consume(future(Arc::clone(&db_ref))); // <------------------- compile error
}

async fn future(db_ref: Arc<db::Database>){ }

fn consume<F>(f: F)
where F: Send{ }
```

The [`postgres::Client`](https://github.com/sfackler/rust-postgres/blob/master/postgres/src/client.rs#L12) is defined as

```
/// A synchronous PostgreSQL client.
pub struct Client {
    connection: Connection,
    client: tokio_postgres::Client,
}
```

When compiling this code the compile I got somewhat crazy error message:

```
error[E0277]: `(dyn futures_core::stream::Stream<Item = std::result::Result<tokio_postgres::AsyncMessage, tokio_postgres::error::Error>> + std::marker::Send + 'static)` cannot be shared between threads safely
  --> src/main.rs:17:5
   |
17 |     consume(future(Arc::clone(&db_ref)));
   |     ^^^^^^^ `(dyn futures_core::stream::Stream<Item = std::result::Result<tokio_postgres::AsyncMessage, tokio_postgres::error::Error>> + std::marker::Send + 'static)` cannot be shared between threads safely
...
24 | fn consume<F>(f: F)
   |    ------- required by a bound in this
25 | where F: Send{ }
   |          ---- required by this bound in `consume`
   |
   = help: the trait `std::marker::Sync` is not implemented for `(dyn futures_core::stream::Stream<Item = std::result::Result<tokio_postgres::AsyncMessage, tokio_postgres::error::Error>> + std::marker::Send + 'static)`
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `std::marker::Sync` for `std::ptr::Unique<(dyn futures_core::stream::Stream<Item = std::result::Result<tokio_postgres::AsyncMessage, tokio_postgres::error::Error>> + std::marker::Send + 'static)>`
   = note: required because it appears within the type `std::boxed::Box<(dyn futures_core::stream::Stream<Item = std::result::Result<tokio_postgres::AsyncMessage, tokio_postgres::error::Error>> + std::marker::Send + 'static)>`
   = note: required because it appears within the type `std::pin::Pin<std::boxed::Box<(dyn futures_core::stream::Stream<Item = std::result::Result<tokio_postgres::AsyncMessage, tokio_postgres::error::Error>> + std::marker::Send + 'static)>>`
   = note: required because it appears within the type `postgres::connection::Connection`
   = note: required because it appears within the type `postgres::client::Client`
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `std::marker::Send` for `std::sync::Arc<postgres::client::Client>`
   = note: required because it appears within the type `db::Database`
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `std::marker::Send` for `std::sync::Arc<db::Database>`
   = note: required because it appears within the type `[static generator@src/main.rs:22:43: 22:46 db_ref:std::sync::Arc<db::Database> {}]`
   = note: required because it appears within the type `std::future::from_generator::GenFuture<[static generator@src/main.rs:22:43: 22:46 db_ref:std::sync::Arc<db::Database> {}]>`
   = note: required because it appears within the type `impl core::future::future::Future`
   = note: required because it appears within the type `impl core::future::future::Future`
```

Which seems to mean that `Database` does not implement `Send`. Is there a way to make implement `Send`? Maybe `Mutex` or something else should be used instead of `Arc`?

**UPD:**

Replacing the struct definition with

```
pub struct Database{
    connection: Mutex<Client>
}
```

makes the error disappear, but it is completely unclear why...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Arc<T>` allows multiple threads to access the same value *at the same time*. The `Sync` trait is what verifies that the access will not cause memory unsafety, hence why `Arc` requires it.

On the other hand, `Mutex<T>` controls access to `T` via locking, so that only one thread may access `T` at a time (in a sense, 'sending' it to the thread that has the lock). So `Mutex<T>` is `Sync` even if `T` is not (though it still must be `Send`).

However `Mutex<T>` on its own isn't useful since only one thread will have access to the mutex anyway. You usually combine it with a way of sharing ownership (i.e. `Arc`) to allow multiple threads to have access the mutex.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this was that the trait implementation `Send for Arc` [was defined](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.Arc.html#impl-Send) as

```
impl<T> Send for Arc<T>
where
    T: Send + Sync + ?Sized,
```

So `Sync` is required to be implemented as well. And that's what the error message was saying. For `Mutex` in turns `Send` [is defined](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.Mutex.html#impl-Send) as

```
impl<T: ?Sized + Send> Send for Mutex<T>
```

not requiring `Sync` to be implemented.